# What's the purpose of a settable md5Hash in UploadMetadata?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties

I tried just setting it to `bob` to see if it did anything.

Nope, when upload finishes, it seems to be set to the actual file hash.

I could imagine a world where if the provided md5Hash doesn't match the file contents the upload fails – but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>[Firebase Storage Web SDK dev here]</sub>

> I could imagine a world where if the provided md5Hash doesn't match the file contents the upload fails – but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Yeah, that's the idea. We built the SDK to support that, but the hash verification functionality isn't currently implemented.

As you observed, setting the `md5Hash` property doesn't do anything (at time of writing).

Comment: Good to know. It'd be *great* if this fact was explained in the documentation.